# I cannot clone git tree

Tags: linux, git

I have a question about git, I tried to clone a tree but without success.

```
git clone https://github.com/cer/event-sourcing-examples/tree/d2077e21aa677a00095f90250470ff011c132ab8/java-spring
```

I cloned the project

```
git clone https://github.com/cer/event-sourcing-examples
```

and I tried to switch to that tree but no effect

Would you have any suggestions ?

Best regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Git cannot clone a tree directly. You need to clone the entire repository, and then check out a commit that uses the tree you want. For the sake of reducing confusions, though, do note that there is a difference between the terms "tree" and "commit", though:

- A tree is a Git object representing a directory, and contains links to blobs (files) and other trees. A tree is not necessarily the root directory of the repository.
- A commit object contains a link to the *root* tree of the repository, and some extra information such as commit message, dates and other headers.

You can only check out commits. Few Git commands deal directly with tree objects (`git cat-file` and `git ls-tree` being among the exceptions). However, the object ID in your GitHub URL is indeed the ID of a commit, so that's not a problem.

What you can do, then, is check out the commit you want into a new branch after you've cloned the repository:

```sh
git checkout -b test-branch d2077e21
```

If the problem you're trying to solve is just fetching a single commit (or tree) from a remote repository, then you're out of luck, because Git's remote protocol does not support that operation. If anything, if you can insert a branch into the remote repository at the commit you want, you can clone that branch directly, without any history:

```sh
git clone -b test-branch --depth 1 https://github.com/cer/event-sourcing-examples
```

If you can't do that, however, then you're still out of luck. The remote protocol only allows referencing named refs, not arbitrary commits.

Comment: got same problem but in one branch and i just wanna go to previous tree,, so i just `git checkout <treeNumber>` and then `git pull origin master` ?

Answer (score 7):

Check if below things helps.Am using a GIT bash here.

1. Clone the repository.

   `git clone https://github.com/cer/event-sourcing-examples.git`
2. Enter that directory

   `cd event-sourcing-examples/`
3. Switch the branch(i am assuming by tree you mean branch)

   `git checkout wip-vagrant` wip-vagrant is a branch name
4. To get the update you have to issue a pull command.

   `git pull`

If you directly want to clone the branch then follow the instructions in above comment(Micheal).

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is just to get a copy of the repo at a particular commit...

While you can't use clone, **you can download a zip file** of the repo at a particular commit.

This method works on GitHub.

This and other approaches can be found at:
https://coderwall.com/p/xyuoza/git-cloning-specific-commits

TL;DR

Navigate to the tree view of the sha you want.

`https://github.com/<repo_name>/tree/<commit_sha>`

Download the zip file.
Don't clone.

```
Github Tree View

 Open the repo and click the "commits" link 
   (in the bar that says "commits branches packages, etc.)

 Select the commit you want. This will take you to the view showing the changes.
    In the url you will see something like this:
    https://github.com/Colt/webpack-demo-app/commit/eb66c0dc93141080f5b1abb335ec998a1e91d72e

 - Note the sha in the url is preceeded by the word "commit". 
   Replace the word "commit" with the word "tree" to put yourself in the
   tree view. 

 - Finally, click on the green "Clone or download" button
   and Download the ZIP. Don't try to clone.

   This will download the entire repo as it was at that commit.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

Example:

```
git clone -b my-branch git@github.com:user/myproject.git
```

Alternative (no public key setup needed):

```
git clone -b my-branch https://git@github.com/username/myproject.git
```

Comment: I think that my question wasn't very clear. what I need is clonnig the tree content not the master by using  **git clone https://github.com/cer/event-sourcing-examples**

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the complete repo and get checkout the repo to commit_sha.

```
git clone -n <repo_name> 
git checkout <commit_sha>
```