# checking out a branch from GitHub remotely

Tags: github

I'm trying to checkout branch remotely with fetch command and get the following error:  What is correct syntax?  HelloWorld2 is my master branch.

```
 git fetch https://github.com/abc/HelloWorld2/tree/DevBranch

 fatal:'https://github.com/abc/HelloWorld2/tree/DevBranch' not found
```

Comment: Within your repo, `git checkout DevBranch`

Comment: Duplicated of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411941/i-cannot-clone-git-tree?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot clone git tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411941/i-cannot-clone-git-tree)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realized I needed to clone master in a local directory.

```
    git clone https://github.com/abc/HelloWorld2.git
```

and then in my local computer directory:

```
    cd HelloWorld2
    git checkout DevBranch
```